# Lightweight open source software synth library on pure C (possibly C++). PCM.?

Tags: c, pcm, sound-synthesis

Are there any portable open source libraries that support sample-based synthesis and encapsulate producing and mixing simple PCMs?

I really need something minimalistic and decoupled from operating system audio output mechanisms.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[csound](http://www.csounds.com/) has a [C api](http://csound.sourceforge.net/refman.pdf) and can handle PCM. [ffmpeg](http://ffmpeg.org/) can also convert lots of popular formats in PCM.